# C# Is there a way to get properties of a class without instancing it?

Tags: c#, xml, properties

I want to get the property names of a C# class without instancing it, so I can compare it to the contents of a XML file.

For example, let's say that I have a class "WeatherInfo":

```
public class WeatherInfo
{
    public string Temperature {get; set;}
    public string Humidity {get; set;}
}
```

and a XML File with:

```
...
<Temperature>...</Temperature>
...
```

Now I want to write some code that checks if the properties of the class are the same as the properties of the XML-File.

In this example I want the code to return Humidity, because it is included in the class, but not in the XML-File.

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I have many classes and XML-files that I have to go through so it would be hard to instance every single class, thats why I am lookin for a better solution.

Comment: Use reflection.

Comment: But isnt reflection for objects? I cant create an object of my class. I have to find a way to do this without writing `WeatherInfo info = new WeatherInfo();`

Comment: Reflection is for types, not for objects. It can interact with objects using their type information.

Comment: `typeof(WeatherInfo).GetProperties().Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList();`